# Error al empaquetar extensión Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-webextensions

Estoy intentando empaquetar una extensión Firefox que desarrollé pero al intentar instalarla me dice:

> Este complemento no ha podido ser instalado porque parece que está dañado.

Ya he probado con **Firefox Quantum** y con la versión **Nightly** a ver si las versiones tenían algo que ver pero nada, he seguido las instrucciones de [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Packaging_and_installation) y tampoco, lo hago al pie de la letra, selecciono los archivos mas no la carpeta, lo comprimo en formato **.ZIP** y luego le cambio la extensión a **.XPI**

También he seguido todas las instrucciones del [Siguiente Hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240653/how-to-create-xpi-file-with-7zip) del Foro en Ingles, aún nada, he probado realizar la compresión con **7-Zip** que he leído que es más recomendable, tampoco, y bueno, cabe aclarar que con **Winrar** también he intentado. No creo que el problema sea con la extensión porque funciona perfectamente cuando la pruebo en el modo depuración. Dejo mi árbol de directorios por si sirve de algo.

```
CARPETA_DE_LA_EXTENSIÓN
├───content
│   ├───info.html
│   └───popup.html
├───images
│   ├───baricon.png
│   ├───icono128.png
│   ├───icono16.png
│   └───icono48.png
├───js
│   └───myjs.js
├───style
│   ├───css.css
│   └───materialize.css
├───background.js
└───manifest.json
```

Comment: _StackOverflow_ no es un foro con hilos, es una plataforma de preguntas y respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Según el [enlace de *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Packaging_and_installation), la carpeta no tiene que ir en el archivo comprimido, en vez de eso, hay que seleccionar todos los archivos y carpetas que están dentro de la carpeta principal y comprimirlo.

> Un truco es que el archivo ZIP debe ser un archivo que contenga los archivos de la extensión y no la carpeta que los contiene.

Solo eso debería solucionarlo.

Comment: Empaquetamos la extensión sin la carpeta, ya sabiamoa eso.

Comment: @qwerty ¿A ti también te sucede lo mismo que el que preguntó?

Comment: Sí, como el lo dijo, seguí la guía dwl MDN y demás y no funciona

Comment: @qwerty ¿Podrías publicar la extensión?